# My flash custom event doesn't trigger

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

There is no trace output of my custom event why ?

CustomEvent class with value property:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;

     public class CustomEvent extends Event
     {
        public static const ON_CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "onCustomEvent";
        public var value:Number;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false):void
        {
           super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
        }

     }

}
```

Test class with a slider which just re-dispatches the slider event:

```
package {

    import flash.display.*;
    import flash.net.*;
    import flash.events.*;
    import fl.events.SliderEvent;
    import fl.controls.Slider;

    public class TestCustomEvent extends MovieClip {        

      private var cEvent: CustomEvent;

      public function TestCustomEvent() {   

        addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);  

      }

      public function init( e:Event ):void {

        removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init );

        this.addEventListener(CustomEvent.ON_CUSTOM_EVENT,OnCustomEvent);
        slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE,OnSliderEventChange);

      } 



      public function OnCustomEvent(event:CustomEvent): void {

            trace(event.value);
      }


      public function OnSliderEventChange(event:SliderEvent) {

            cEvent = new CustomEvent("OnCustomEvent");
            cEvent.value = event.value;
            dispatchEvent(cEvent);
                    trace("hello");

      }

    }       
}
```

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose with the dispatcher's code. Is `OnSliderEventChange` triggered?

Comment: Scroll down in the code window. I didn't notice that at first too.

Comment: All right, then: is `OnSliderEventChange` triggered?

Comment: yes OnSliderEventChange is triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ON_CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "**onCustomEvent**"

*versus*

cEvent = new CustomEvent("**OnCustomEvent**");

(case problem)

You shouldn't write the string the second time but use `CustomEvent.ON_CUSTOM_EVENT`

Comment: weird I did the same for EventDispatcher class but it doesn't work http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5586830/doesnt-receive-event-from-eventdispatcher-class-in-flash

Comment: The difference is the "o" at the start of the string.. One is uppercase, one is lowercase. That string is the identifier of the event.. so with you dispatch you say "anything that is listening for this exact string, run that function". If the strings are not exact, including upper/lowercase, then it thinks they are two different things.

Answer (score 3):

The event object is initialized to "OnCustomEvent" but the static constant ON_CUSTOM_EVENT is "OnCustomChange"

I would recommend using the static constant in both places to make sure it's the same.

Comment: oh thanks. fyi others, he's talking about the website in my profile

Comment: ok thanks but doesn't still work. Event object is created but dispatch does nothiNG;

Answer (score 1):

I like to use a * wildcard arg type, like so:

```
package {

    import flash.events.Event;

     public class CustomEvent extends Event
     {
        public static const ON_CUSTOM_EVENT:String = "onCustomChange";
        public var args:*;

        public function CustomEvent(type:String, bubbles:Boolean=false, cancelable:Boolean=false, ...a:*):void
        {
           super(type, bubbles, cancelable);
           arg = a;
        }

        override public function clone():Event //dont forget your clone override in custom events
        {
            return new CustomEvent(type, bubbles, cancelable, arg);
        }


     }

}
```

Which then allows for multiple arguments of any type to be passed. Just make sure you enforce type on the callers end.

```
    public function OnCustomEvent(event:CustomEvent): void {

                trace(event.arg[0] as Number);
          }


          public function OnSliderEventChange(event:SliderEvent) 
          {
          // here, we use the CustomEvents own static const as the event
          //and pass the event.value as a final parameter, in one statement.

                this.dispatchEvent = new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.ON_CUSTOM_EVENT, false, false, event.value); 
          }
```

Hope that helps

Comment: This is how to set up and use flexible custom events. If you've implemented it and your event still doesn't fire, then look at your OnSliderEventChange. You say its firing, are you tracing it out or something unexplained in your code?

Answer (score 0):

The following is an example of how to use a custom event(you can copy and paste all the code into your document class):

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var _sliderSprite:SliderSprite;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            _sliderSprite = new SliderSprite();
            _sliderSprite.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            _sliderSprite.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
            addChild(_sliderSprite);
            _sliderSprite.addEventListener(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, onSliderSpriteCustomEventType);

        }// end function

        private function onSliderSpriteCustomEventType(e:CustomEvent):void
        {
            trace(e.value);

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package

import fl.controls.Slider;
import fl.events.SliderEvent;
import flash.display.Sprite;

internal class SliderSprite extends Sprite
{
    private var _slider:Slider;

    public function SliderSprite()
    {
        init();

    }// end function

    private function init():void
    {
        _slider = new Slider();
        addChild(_slider);

        _slider.addEventListener(SliderEvent.CHANGE, onSliderChange);

    }// end function

    private function onSliderChange(e:SliderEvent):void
    {
        dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent(CustomEvent.CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE, e.value));

    }// end function

}// end class

import flash.events.Event;

internal class CustomEvent extends Event
{
    public static const CUSTOM_EVENT_TYPE:String = "customEventType";
    private var _value:Number;

    public function get value():Number
    {
        return _value;

    }// end function

    public function CustomEvent(type:String, 
                                value:Number,
                                bubbles:Boolean = false,
                                cancelable:Boolean = false)
    {
        _value = value;

        super(type, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

    override public function clone():Event
    {
        return new CustomEvent(type, value, bubbles, cancelable);

    }// end function

}// end class
```