# Can flash object dispatch custom event to itself?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My prog here doesn't work there's no syntax error
[My flash custom event doesn't trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582398/my-flash-custom-event-doesnt-trigger)

so my question is can flash object dispatch custom event to itself because that's what I wanna do ?

Comment: In your previous question you can see that I answered that question already.

Comment: This is the same problem as your other post. And the answer is yes. You should close this one :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [My flash custom event doesn't trigger](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5582398/my-flash-custom-event-doesnt-trigger)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you want to launch an event to the same object? You should just call a function with the correct parameters instead of firing a custom event to the same object.

Comment: because it's a callback from another object